# How can I load Template file from wordpress plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, templates, page-template

I have created a plugin which displays testimonials and when each is clicked it redirects to the single page. So I wrote this code which is directing properly the single view to the one I created but only in that page its giving me an undefined `get_header();` and `get_footer()`

```php
//controller
class Jetty_Testimonials_Display_Single_Template{

  public function init(){

    //add_filter( 'template_include', array($this, 'jetty_get_template_hierarchy'));
    add_filter( 'template_include', array($this, 'jetty_template_chooser'), 99);

  }

  public function jetty_template_chooser( $template ) {

      $post_id = get_the_ID();

    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) != 'jetty-testimonials' ) {
        return $template;
    }

    if ( is_single()  ) {
            return plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '../templates/single-jetty-testimonial.php';
    }

  }
```

```php
<?php
/**
 *@uses output the single testimonial details
 * @package jetty-testimonials
 * @version 1.0.0
 */

get_header(); ?>
            <?php
            global $post_id;

            print_r($post_id);
            /* Start the Loop
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );

            endwhile; // End of the loop.*/
            ?>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check below code : change Page slug "gym-dashboard" as per your requirement.

```
<?php
function rt_include_gym_dashboard_page_template( $template ) {
    if ( is_page( 'gym-dashboard' )  ) {
            return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/content-gym-dashboard.php';
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'rt_include_gym_dashboard_page_template', 99 );
```